# Continuing get request from where it left off after hitting rate limit?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I found a script that I can use to create a list of all the people a twitter user is following (in this case "@kingjames"). There used to be a private method `next_cursor` that was somehow public in the Twitter API, but now it's really private in that I can't call it and it throws an error if I try.

Removing all references to `next_cursor` in the script below gets rid of the error message but the script doesn't have a way to start adding users. The script has to pause for 15 minutes due to rate limits from where it left off, so it's adding the same users over and over again.

Can you suggest a way to change the script to make it continue from where it left off so the same users aren't added over and over again?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'twitter'



def fetch_all_friends(twitter_username, max_attempts = 100)
  # in theory, one failed attempt will occur every 15 minutes, so this could be long-running
  # with a long list of friends
  num_attempts = 0
  client = client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key     = "8nwjpoIsqag..."
  config.consumer_secret  = "Wj20rZEfPsyHd0KnW..."
  config.access_token     = "363090951-n5NdXfp5wWCkNU5eY..."
  config.access_token_secret = "7eydU2nQHMsSVB8W76Z2PKH1P...."
end

  myfile = File.new("#{twitter_username}_friends_list.txt", "w")
  running_count = 0
  cursor = -1
  while (cursor != 0) do
    begin
      num_attempts += 1
      # 200 is max, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list
      friends = client.friends(twitter_username, {:cursor => cursor, :count => 200} )
      # friends = client.friends(twitter_username ).take(200) //seems like another way to get 200 users
      friends.each do |f|
        running_count += 1
        myfile.puts "\"#{running_count}\",\"#{f.name.gsub('"','\"')}\",\"#{f.screen_name}\",\"#{f.id}\""
      end
      puts "#{running_count} done"
      # cursor = friends.next_cursor
      # break if cursor == 0
    rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
      if num_attempts <= max_attempts
        # cursor = friends.next_cursor if friends && friends.next_cursor
        puts "#{running_count} done from rescue block..."

        puts "Hit rate limit, sleeping for #{error.rate_limit.reset_in}..."
        sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in
        retry
      else
        raise
      end
    end
  end
end

fetch_all_friends("kingjames")
```

Comment: I just wrote a blog post on how to do this with the Yelp api [here](http://allcentury.github.io/blog/2014/07/08/make-multiple-api-calls-using-limit-and-offset/).  Let me see if it works for Twitter as well

Comment: @anthony ok thanks, please post an answer when you can

Comment: The trick is to not hit the limit. Throttle your code, either by deliberately sleeping between loops, or find a way to break down the queries and pause when you've reached a pre-determined limit. Blasting requests and hitting the limit isn't being a good network citizen so learn how to make your code behave better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There used to be a private method next_cursor that was somehow public
>   in the Twitter api but now it's really private in that you can't call
>   it and it throws an error if you try.

There is no restriction in ruby against calling private methods.  The only restriction is that you can't explicitly specify the receiver when you call a private method.  Here is an example:

```
class Dog
  private
  def next_cursor
    puts "I'm the next cursor."
  end
end


friends = Dog.new
friends.next_cursor

--output:--
1.rb:10:in `<main>': private method `next_cursor' called for #<Dog:0x00000100a40fc8> (NoMethodError)

friends.instance_eval do
  next_cursor   #You can't explicitly specify a receiver for a private method, 
                #and ruby uses whatever object is self as the receiver
end

--output:--
I'm the next cursor.
```

If you don't know the ins and outs of Ruby, then that code will seem pretty confusing.  But Ruby also provides a method named send(), which allows you to call any method:

```
friends.send(:next_cursor)

--output:--
I'm the next cursor.
```

Comment: actually that makes sense but you can't use `send()` in this line of code can you `cursor = friends.next_cursor if friends && friends.next_cursor`  how would I get around the need to access the private method next_cursor here (since this is part of the script that I need to use)

Comment: I'm going to try this `cursor = friends.send(:next_cursor) if friends && friends.send(:next_cursor)`

Comment: @Leachim, your condition in the rescue clause is wacky `cursor = friends.next_cursor if friends && friends.next_cursor`.  That may end up calling next_cursor() twice, and it's more efficient to only have to call next_cursor() once: `cursor = friends.send(:next_cursor); if friends and cursor ....#do something`

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but can't understand how this script works, can anyone help me? I'll ask a question if I have to. @7stud

Comment: @marriedjane875, which are you having trouble understanding: send() or instance_eval()?

Comment: I'm still learning how to effectively use the "cursor = -1" method in twitter gem. But then I want to incorporate the save gathered request in order to get ALL of a friends list. @7stud

Comment: @marriedjane875, I don't have any knowledge about Twitter's API, so I don't have any idea what you are talking about, so you should ask a question, or direct your comment to Leahcim.

Comment: hey @Leahcim can you help me understand how the cursor method work with twitter api? I'm having trouble getting the loop to work even once.

Comment: right now my error is: "private method `next_cursor' called for #<Twitter::Cursor:0x007fd47482a208> (NoMethodError)" @7stud

Comment: @marriedjane875, Okay on the line with the error, just like my answer recommended to Leahcim, replace `friends.next_cursor` with `friends.send(:next_cursor)`, then do that replacement throughout your code. Also, in the comments I corrected an if statement, which you should also replace in Leahcim's code.